# No dynamic symbol in a DLL cross-compiled on Linux

Tags: linux, dll, cross-compiling

I've created a DLL on Linux (CentOS 6.7) with MXE (a MinGW cross-compile environment on Linux) static toolchain. If it does not link with glib, everything looks fine. However, if it links with glib, `dumpbin /exports libtest.dll` only show the symbols in glib (prefixed with `g_`, eg `g_int_equal`).

For example, the small test c code

```
#include <glib.h>

int global_func(void)
{
  int c = 0xff;
  return c;
}

int local_func(int ini)
{
  int a = 1, b = 2;
  g_int_equal(&a, &b);
  return ini + 1;
}
```

The command to build the DLL:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-gcc -c -o test.o test.c -I/home/STools/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/STools/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/lib/glib-2.0/include
x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -Wl,-soname,libtest.dll -Wl,--version-script=test.version -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--no-seh -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--warn-common -m64 -g -shared -o libtest.dll test.o -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv -lwinmm -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -lole32
```

The version script, test.version:

```
FOO {
global:
    global_func;
local: *;   # hide everything else
};
```

Then I dump the exported symbols in libtest.dll in Windows with:

```
dumpbin /exports libtest.dll
```

It shows a lot of functions in glib, but no "global_func".

Glib here is static library. I also tried the shared toolchain, x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-g++. With static Glib, the result is the same. So, when I try to find some function in the DLL with GetProcAddress, it fails.
Anything wrong?

I've also downloaded the DLL version of Glib from gnome website. Now the exported functions are right.

Comment: Are you using the dllexport attribute (__declspec(dllexport))? Remember that ELF and DLLs are totally different one to another. Also, please try to post a minimal example, one which others can work upon.

Comment: @borancar No, I'm using linker version script.There's no ELF. I'm cross-compiling DLL on Linux.